# Getting Error when trying to use getembeddings function

Tags: python, vector, embedding, openai-api

So what I am trying to do here is for my code to read and interpet an excel sheet and use a semantic Search to find he closest datapoints using vectors and FAISS, I am running into an issue when i call .getembeddings.

Here is my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS 



# Set OpenAI API Key
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""

# Initialize classes
embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()

# Load data from Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('sampledata.xlsx')

# We'll use the 'Item' column for creating our vector database
texts = df['Item'].tolist()

text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter.from_tiktoken_encoder(chunk_size=10, chunk_overlap=0)

split_texts = []
for text in texts:
    docs = text_splitter.split_text(text)
    for d in docs:
        split_texts.append(d)

# Vector DB creation
vectordb = FAISS.from_texts(texts=split_texts, embedding=embedding)  # remove persist_directory


# Query
query = "Pen"
query_vector = embedding.get_embeddings([query])

# Search
top_k = 10  # number of results to return
distances, indices = vectordb.search(query_vector, top_k)

# Print the results
for i in range(top_k):
    print(f"Item: {texts[indices[i]]}, Distance: {distances[i]}")

vectordb = None

vectordb = None
```

The Error i am receiving is

```
> File "c:\Users\rbalakrishnan\OneDrive - Eastside Preparatory School\Terawe\pdfreader.py", line 33, in <module>
> query_vector = embedding.get_embeddings([query])

 query_vector = embedding.get_embeddings([query])
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'OpenAIEmbeddings' object has no attribute 'get_embeddings'
```

Comment: Why do you believe that object **should** have a `.get_embeddings()` function attribute?  Did you read that in a tutorial?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you might be blocked by openai. Maybe try and switch to a VPN and see how that works out?

Cheers

Edit:

Since the error is now related only to the get_embeddings call. I believe you should try and  define your get_embeddings function first.

OpenAI docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/use-cases

Comment: Network blocks could not possibly cause this kind of error.

Comment: Indeed. But before he edited the post, this was the full log:

"openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating 
 withquery_vector OpenAI:= HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openaiembedding.com', port=443get_embeddings([query]): 
 Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/engines/text-embedding-ada-002/embeddings (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000258D3B02E10>: Failed to resolve 'api.openai.com' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)"))^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"

Maybe that threw me off? Who knows

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).